# Using image maps with text somehow (jquery?)

Tags: jquery, css, imagemap

First of all, I know image maps are kind of outdated, but they're not deprecated yet, and neat enough! I'm upgrading an existing and really cluttered image map, which is being used to show the work of different labs around the world in an area of chemistry research, and really just trying to tackle a coding/design problem for myself.

I'm wondering how I might go about coupling a rollover image fade (e.g. [for individual countries](http://www.svennerberg.com/examples/imagemap_rollover/index_jquery_fade.html)) with text (i.e. captions rather than a URL with text tip). The map is rendered and setting coordinates is a simple enough matter, but I need some way to produce links on rollover, such as for [Researcher 1 | lab website],[Researcher 2 | lab website], etc. in particular for when they reside in the same place on the map.

All I can seem to see being done to make these interactive from other examples is alerts and single links for a region of an image map, but I'm sure it could be more versatile and I'm wondering if anyone knows how I could present text in this way?

[Something that acts like this](http://ec.europa.eu/research/infrastructures/index_en.cfm?pg=mapri) (all the labs expand out when you want to look more closely) would be great.

I'm sorry I can't be more constructive but the code is too dense for me to work out how that's done, and I get the feeling I might be missing some basic solution...?

Thanks

Comment: It wouldn't let me post this image (since this is my first question!), but [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xFsyH.jpg) might help give an idea of what the really static situation is like at the moment.

Comment: cant believe you are not using google maps or something similar. You can get a rough poly of every country and mark it as you want.

Comment: Sounds like Google maps is a good solution for you problem. Have you seen their example javascript apps?

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for the tip off, I've looked into it and I'm having a go at a fusion table, looks effective.

Comment: @Jasen I haven't, I think I may have stumbled upon it now - is [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery) it?

Comment: Yes, but you want to be sure to use version 3 API.

Comment: @Jasen Yeah noticed they deprecated v2, got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group image maps to a div and then set it to hidden by default
on hover to certain part set the group to visible by JavaScript

Comment: Ah interesting solution, I've gone and retrieved all the geolocation data into a spreadsheet now so I can place markers automatically - if this was a smaller map that'd be a good idea though. Cheers

Comment: Well I was intending to use a simple image map, but it's for 126 points on a map so I've got a Google Spreadsheet linking into Javascript within html to produce an interactive Google Map, with the added benefit of clustering maybe. If it's no trouble though (since I may have to make a smaller imagemap at some point) would you be able to point me to some code for grouping image maps to a div?

Comment: yeah might be difficult lets see if we get any other answers